# Combining 2 or more `grep -A` output

Tags: shell, grep

This is my sample data

```
Apple 13
Apple 37
Apple 341
Apple 27B
Apple 99
Banana 00
Banana 988
Banana 507
Banana 11
Banana 11A
```

I would like to get the output like this

```
Apple 13
Apple 37
Apple 341
Banana 00
Banana 988
```

The problem is I can only do grep with switch `-A 2` one time only

```
root@Ubuntu:/tmp# grep -A 2 'e 1' data.txt  
Apple 13
Apple 37
Apple 341
root@Ubuntu:/tmp#
```

Another `grep -A 1`

```
root@Ubuntu:/tmp# grep -A 1 'a 0' data.txt  
Banana 00
Banana 988
root@Ubuntu:/tmp#
```

I've been trying to use egrep but I did not get the output that I wanted.

```
root@Ubuntu:/tmp# egrep 'e 1|a 0' data.txt 
Apple 13
Banana 00
root@Ubuntu:/tmp#
```

I would like to get 2 more line after `Apple 13` and 1 more line after `Banana 00`

Please advise

Comment: @CharlotteRussel: My advise would be not to use grep for this problem. You don't use a scissor to cut off a slice of meat, even if it is a good scissor. grep was not intended to solve this type of problems. I would write a small script in, say, awk or Ruby or Perl, or whatever programmin language you are fluent at. You can even do it in a good shell scripting language, such as bash or Zsh.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/e 1/{N;N;p}; /a 0/{N;p}' file
```

Output:

```
Apple 13
Apple 37
Apple 341
Banana 00
Banana 988
```

---

See: `man sed`

Answer (score 2):

I'll recommend **awk** or **sed** to solve these kind of problems

using **awk**

```
$ awk ' /e 1/{i=1; t=3} /a 0/{i=1; t=2} i++<=t' file
Apple 13
Apple 37
Apple 341
Banana 00
Banana 988
```

`i` : iterator
`t` : threshold

`/e 1/{i=1; t=3}` : If string contains `e 1` then set `i=1` and `t=3` .
`t=3` because in total 3 lines needs to be printed (including matched line)

`/a 0/{i=1; t=2}` : If string contains `a 0` then set `i=1` and `t=2`

`i++<=t` : if it's true , then print line.  `i++` to increment `i` after each check

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any idea to solve this problem by a single command. If you don't mind using couple of commands, please use the following,

```
grep -A 2 "e 1" test.txt && grep -A 1 "a 0" test.txt
```